# Mysterious "More" tab shown for one user

Tags: feed-based-layout

One of our users is complaining about a More tab. This is visible on Account Feed Based pages. He sees the tabs Feed, Details and, wait for it, More. The tab More cannot be clicked on.

[image]

Also: the action buttons that normally appear under the More dropdown menu, Link and Poll, are visible, wrapped around. The More dropdown menu is itself also still visible. The left pane, with recent items, is collapsed.

The action buttons are not usable anymore. This is where the user starts complaining.

The user says that the More tab is only visible when he is working on the move. I still have to ask him what is so special about "on the move". From his login history I can see that he is always using IE11 under Win7.

I have tried to replicate or google this, but I have no idea where that More tab is coming from.

Anybody ever seen this?

Comment: IE 11 is officially not supported. Did you enable [Extended IE 11 Support](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000233325&language=en_US&type=1)? I can't guarantee it'll fix the problem, but it's a place to start.

Comment: We have enabled that and I am confident that that is not the problem. My gut feeling tells me it's more a feature than a bug, and somehow this user has been able to unlock this feature.

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot of what the user is seeing?

Comment: @sfdcfox I always thought it was not possible to post pictures on StackExchange, but it is. I just attached the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my suggestion, the user has switched to Firefox and hasn't encountered this problem since.